# Implementing Oauth in WCF REST Service(Siganture Not Matching)

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, oauth

I m implementing Oauth in my WCF RESTful Service, In Client Side i m generating signature(siganture reference [link1](http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/hmac-sha1.js) , [link2](http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/components/enc-base64-min.js)) using script ([script reference](https://github.com/ddo/oauth-1.0a)) and In server side i m generating signature using c# ([code reference](https://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/csharp/OAuthBase.cs)), All are working fine, But the only thing is client side generating signature is not matching with the server side generating signature.

Here is my code , pls point out where i m doing mistake

SCRIPT:

```
$("#BtnCheck").click(function () {

    oauth = OAuth({
        consumer: {
            public: 'test',
            secret: 'secret'
        },
        signature_method: 'HMAC-SHA1'
    });

   request_data = {
     //  url: 'http://MyPcName/RestfulService/Login/LoginService.svc/GetSampleMethod_With_OAuth/inputStr/validate',
       url: 'http://localhost/RestfulService/Login/LoginService.svc/GetSampleMethod_With_OAuth/inputStr/validate',
        method: 'GET',
        data: {
            status: 'Hello Ladies + Gentlemen, a signed OAuth request!'
        }
    };
   varType = "GET";
   varUrl = "http://localhost/RestfulService/Login/LoginService.svc/GetSampleMethod_With_OAuth/inputStr/validate";
   data = oauth.authorize(request_data, null);
   varContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
   varDataType = "json";
   varProcessData = false;
   varCache = false
   varData = data;
   CallService(Authenticate);
});

function Authenticate(response) {
    var data = response
    alert(response);
}
```

CALL SERVICE:

```
function CallService(sucessData) {
    $.ajax({
        //headers: getHeaders(),
        type: varType, //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb
        url: varUrl, // Location of the service
        data: varData, //Data sent to server
        contentType: varContentType, // content type sent to server
        dataType: varDataType, //Expected data format from server
        processdata: varProcessData, //True or False
        crossDomain: true,
        timeout: 200000,
        success: sucessData,
        cache: varCache,
        error: function (xhr) {// When Service call fails
            alert("Error: " + xhr.responseText);
            //alert('Error occured in Service Call');
        }
    });
}
```

WCF SERVICE:

```
        [OperationContract(Name = "GetSampleMethod_With_OAuth")]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "GetSampleMethod_With_OAuth/inputStr/{name}")]
        string GetSampleMethod_With_OAuth(string name);

 public string GetSampleMethod_With_OAuth(string strUserName)
        {
            if (Authenticate(WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest))
            {
                StringBuilder strReturnValue = new StringBuilder();
                // return username prefixed as shown below
                strReturnValue.Append(string.Format("AUTHORIZED REQUEST"));
                return strReturnValue.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
                return "401 Unauthorized Request.";
            }
      }
        private static bool Authenticate(IncomingWebRequestContext context)
        {
            bool Authenticated = false;
            string normalizedUrl;
            string normalizedRequestParameters;
            //context.Headers
            NameValueCollection pa = context.UriTemplateMatch.QueryParameters;
            if (pa != null && pa["oauth_consumer_key"] != null)
            {
                // to get uri without oauth parameters
                string uri = context.UriTemplateMatch.RequestUri.OriginalString.Replace
                    (context.UriTemplateMatch.RequestUri.Query, "");
                string consumersecret = "secret";
                OAuthBase oauth = new OAuthBase();
                string hash = oauth.GenerateSignature(
                    new Uri(uri),
                    pa["oauth_consumer_key"],
                    consumersecret,
                    null, // totken
                    null, //token secret
                    "GET",
                    pa["oauth_timestamp"],
                    pa["oauth_nonce"],
                    out normalizedUrl,
                    out normalizedRequestParameters
                    );
                Authenticated = pa["oauth_signature"] == hash;
            }
            return Authenticated;
        }
```

Comment: Hi, I am also facing similar issue. Did you find any solution for your problem?

Comment: Yes i found it please see the answer mentioned below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this issue:

In Javascript: Remove the `data:{}` in the `request_data`

```
 request_data = {
     //  url: 'http://MyPcName/RestfulService/Login/LoginService.svc/GetSampleMethod_With_OAuth/inputStr/validate',
       url: 'http://localhost/RestfulService/Login/LoginService.svc/GetSampleMethod_With_OAuth/inputStr/validate',
        method: 'GET',
            };
```